# Styling the picker

Tags: codenameone

I have 3 questions that deals with the picker:

**1)** How can I style the selectedString in the picker? For instance change the foreground color of "Select the model" (setSelectedString) in the following code to grey where as when I click the picker, its string list are red.

```
Picker p = new Picker();
p.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS);
p.setSelectedString("Select the model");
```

**2)** how can I style the border of the picker string?

how it looks now:

[image]

how I want it to looks

[image]

**3)** When you scroll to the last string in the picker list, the first string comes up again. How can I end the picker from scrolling at the end of the picker list?

Answer (score 0):

You can't customize any of that. The picker is implemented in native and as a result our control is very limited.

We are considering lightweight pickers that look more like Androids material pickers (the iOS picker is harder to replicate) but there isn't demand for that from Enterprise users.

Comment: I think cn1 encourages the use of pickers instead of comboBox & others. So if picker is flexible, it'd be great... currently it works nice but it could have been better... Thanks

Comment: I very much agree. The main difficulty is in resources which are already stretched very thinly. I don't want to "oversell" but we really need peoples help with the enterprise accounts so we can grow the team and do more